# How to use highly compressed bundle file (bundle.tar.gz) for hosting in server?

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering

i usually will host react js public folder that include index.html , bundle.js,css, etc...

here my bundle.js is 400kb. i got a way to compress the file to bundle.tar.gz with 112kb. But it cant be used to link as script in index.html

how to use the file bundle.tar.gz for hosting ?

Answer (score 0):

1) Use `compression-webpack-plugin` plugin for production build and algorithm as 'gzip' in react application.

2) Using express to serve compressed content.(Every server has different ways to send .js.gz format) - **Example Node here**

i) Add middleware to return .js.gz.

```
app.get('*.js', function (req, res, next) {
  req.url = req.url + '.gz';
  res.set('Content-Encoding', 'gzip');
  next();
});
```

ii) Add compression package for express

**Note:- Most browsers supports Gzip compression by default.**